# Is this SQL possible in Sequelize?

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

I've just started with sequelize and am trying to reproduce the below query.

I have the following Model structure: `Review`, `Entity`, `ReviewThank`

Each `Entity` can have many `Reviews`, and each `Review` can have many `ReviewThanks`.

An attribute of each review is a '`thumbUp`' (`boolean`) rating.

I'm trying to generate the below query to get a '`thankCount`' for each review, along with the Entity rating - `thumbUpCount` and `totalCount` - for each `Review`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT COUNT("Review"."id") AS "totalCount", "Review"."EntityId", COUNT(CASE WHEN "Review"."thumbUp" THEN 1 END) AS "thumbUpCount"
    FROM "Reviews" AS "Review" GROUP BY "Review"."EntityId"
) AS "EntityRatingTable" LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT "Review"."id", "Review"."EntityId", "Review"."uid", "Review"."thumbUp", "Review"."caption", COUNT("ReviewThanks"."id") AS "thankCount"
    FROM "Reviews" AS "Review" LEFT OUTER JOIN "ReviewThanks" AS "ReviewThanks" ON "Review"."id" = "ReviewThanks"."ReviewId" 
    WHERE "Review"."UserId" IN (1) GROUP BY "Review"."id"
) AS "ReviewsTable" ON "ReviewsTable"."EntityId" = "EntityRatingTable"."EntityId";
```

Is it possible to produce this in sequelize? I've got the "`ReviewsTable`" query working ok, but unsure how (or if possible) I can join this with the "`EntityRatingTable`"?

This is what I've got so far:

```
models.Review.findAll({

    attributes: {
        include: [
            [models.sequelize.fn('COUNT', models.sequelize.col('ReviewThanks.id')), 'thankCount'],
            [models.sequelize.fn('COUNT', models.sequelize.col('Review.id')), 'reviewCount'],
        ],
        exclude: ["EntityId", "UserId"],
    },

    include: [
        {
            model: models.ReviewThank,
            attributes: [],
        }, {
            model: models.Entity,
        }
    ],

    group: ['"Review"."id"', '"Entity.id"'],

})
```

Comment: what's the sql that sequelize outputs for your code?